# How to make qr code app in android for save nickname

Tags: android, database, qr-code

I am new to android application development.I want to develop qr code reader app.
This app want to write nickname.Then It will read qr code.And It save a database this nickname.How to make this app.

Comment: This question is probably too broad for a single answer.  I would start by modifying an open source application for reading QR codes.  Here is a popular open source QR code reader application for Android: https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Comment: Thanks.understand.but I need qr code for save nickname.how to make it

Comment: Take a look at the Android tutorials for using an SQLite database.  https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html